# How can I make the current item stick in a blur menu in CSS3 ? [example tutorial inside]

Tags: html, css, menu

I followed the tutorial
[here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/19/blur-menu-with-css3-transitions/)
to create a blur menu for my portfolio website.

However, I will need help in making sure that when one of these items in the menu is selected it stays unblurred, while the others are blurry to show the user what item he is currently browsing. I would also like the other items to become unblurred once the user mouses over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class to the active item, and style it the same as the hover. For extra fun, you can target the active item to display a little differently during the hover effects.

Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mobidevelop/LPrce/

Comment: No problem. Did my fiddle demonstrate what you were looking for? Or did I misinterpret what you were trying to do?

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for, but it only worked on jsfiddle. On my webpage the active element would always switch to the default one with class active in HTML, when I navigated to a different page. I got around that by setting different active class for elements for different pages.